# Rails 4 Authentication Structure Planning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to plan an authentication and authorization system for my Rails 4 application.

Here is the structure I'm planning:

[Authentication plan for rails application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCI6a.png)

(* Sorry, I can not insert images because of my newby reputation)

I need three different authorization levels (or models, I'm not sure) as; Student, Editor and Admin.

Each of these will be associated with different models. For example Students will be associated with a profile (student has_one profile) but Admins will be associated with both "profile" and "administrative_profile".

I also need a flexible solution for defining Admin detailed and hierarchic admin roles. I mean, all the administrator will not have the same rights, some will be responsible for an institution, some will a city etc. The hierarchy of this structure is;

`CityAdmin > InstitutionAdmin > DepartmentAdmin`

I'm not sure how to build this kind of structure. **What is the best approach to build an authentication structure like this?** Right now, **I have "devise" gem installed and already have a "User" model. What my next step should be?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following the [RBAC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) (role-based access control)? This pattern separates users from the role(s) they play in the system. Permissions are attached to roles, and empower users as needed.

This is not a ultimate solution, but it seems flexible enough for the requirements you have described.

Some gems can help, such as [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or more modern alternatives, in addition/replacing Devise.

Please note there is a difference between authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Check out cancan/rolify

[Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

[Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify)

Another great resource would be to see these in a working starter app.  Go checkout the Rails Composer site and create a new app with Rails 3.2.  There are some great prebuilt starter app seeds for 3.2 you can use as a reference.

Or you can just follow these steps:

```
rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

When creating this app, if you use Rails 3.2, you will see these options:

```
question  Install an example application for Rails 3.2?
      1)  I want to build my own application
      2)  membership/subscription/saas
      3)  rails-prelaunch-signup
      4)  rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan
      5)  rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber
      6)  rails3-mongoid-devise
      7)  rails3-mongoid-omniauth
      8)  rails3-subdomains
```

You can pick #4 and you will have a pre-built starter app with devise/cancan/rolify all setup so you can take a look at a working example.